# Audio resample method in java

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, java-audio

I have a project which is to convert a python audio processing application to Android, which means I need to translate the code from python to java.

The python code uses the librosa library to resample audio files (`librosa.resample(y, orig_samplerate, target_samplerate, res_type='sinc_fastest'`)

Is there any package in java I can use to achieve the same result (have to use the `sinc_fastest` resample type)? I am new to java, please give me some help! Thanks!

`jlibrosa` in java seems have the similar function as the `librosa` in python, but I did not find the resample function.

Comment: The core Java package for audio, which includes format conversion, is `javax.sound.sampled`, with a tutorial for this at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html#114640. But I don't think this package is accessible in Android. However, Android has some pretty excellent tools of its own for audio. I suggest you edit your question to include the `android` or `android-mediaplayer` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I have editted tags.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the terms of the license are compatible with your use case but perhaps [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) is what you are looking for